# Using Eval("Name") in Function

Tags: c#, gridview, eval, webforms

I'm using .NET webforms. I have a grid view that can use Eval("Name") in the markup and it works fine. However, I need to do some computations on it so in the code behind I made a method called FormatName(String name). I can use that in the markup and it works when I pass it a string but not when I when I try to use Eval("Name".

`<%# Eval("Name") %>` works 
`< %# FormatName("jim") %>` works

I'm looking for something like this: 
`<%# FormatName(Eval("Name"))>%`

That doesnt work but I figure there is something close.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<%# FormatName(Eval("Name").ToString())>%` should work. Eval returns an object, not a string.

Another option is the `EvalText` function, which evaluates the value as a string.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'm new to anything web related.

Comment: I have fallen into that trap many times!
Please accept if it solved your problem :)